# Calling non-Javascript code in Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

How does a Visual Studio Code Extension (AFAIK developed with Javascript code) invoke a function which is written in a language other than Javascript, for example, calling a Golang function which parses a C++ code?

Comment: Your extension is no other than a Node.js application itself, so how does Node.js application consume Go libraries? Search engines can reveal the feasible solutions.

Comment: I think of calling non-JS function from Node.js JS code is a sort of loopback-Websocket-JSON  connection. Is this a feasible idea?